# How do you create a vector with a value dependent on boolean in other vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, categorical-data

I want to create a new categorical vector based on the value of another vector. Where each observation is exclusively true for only one vector e.g.

```
v1 v2 v3
0, 1, 0 
1, 0, 0 
1, 0, 0
```

So I want v4 to name which vector is 'true' something like:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4
0, 1, 0, v2
1, 0, 0, v1
1, 0, 0, v1
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on from the other answer, you can compute the matches without a for loop like so (this is also a more dynamic approach, so should also work fine with larger/other tables).

```matlab
% assuming your data is stored in table, t
[indices,~] = find(t.Variables.');
t.v4 = categorical(t.Properties.VariableNames(indices)).';
```

Or in one line

```matlab
t.v4 = categorical(t.Properties.VariableNames(mod(find(t.Variables.')-1,size(t.Variables,2))+1)).';
```